# If-else block and unexpected results with float datatype. [Edited with one more question]

Tags: c, types, literals, if-statement

I compiled the following program with gcc 4.4.1 and I get unexpected output (Well, unexpected for me)

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
        float x=0.3, y=0.7;

        if(x==0.3)
        {
                if(y==0.7)
                        printf("Y\n\n");
                else
                        printf("X\n\n");
        }
        else
                printf("NONE\n\n");
}


Output: NONE
```

---

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
        float x=0.3, y=0.7;

        if(x<0.3)
        {
                if(y==0.7)
                        printf("Y\n\n");
                else
                        printf("X\n\n");
        }
        else
                printf("NONE\n\n");
}

Output: NONE
```

---

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
        float x=0.3, y=0.7;

        if(x>0.3)
        {
                if(y>0.7)
                        printf("Y\n\n");
                else
                        printf("X\n\n");
        }
        else
                printf("NONE\n\n");
}

    Output:X
```

So, it's clearly visible that the stored value in "x" is greater than 0.3 and the stored value in "y" is less than 0.7

Why is this happening? Is this a property of float datatype or the if-else statements interpret float in a different way?

Thanks.

---

Edit: Alright, I pondered it over and I'm getting a little confused now. Kindly tell if my understanding of this problem is correct or not.

```
float x=0.3;
```

This stores `x=0.30000001192092895508` in the memory. Clearly, this is greater than `0.3` (Is this correct?)

Now, `double x=0.3` results in `x=0.29999999999999998890` and this is smaller than 0.3 (Is this correct too?)

Main question:
So if I use store `0.3` in `float x`, then the following statement `if(x>0.3)` results in `x=0.30000001192092895508` being implicitly casted as a double and 0.3 is also a double instead of a float. Hence `0.3=0.29999999999999998890` and the internal operation is `if((double) 0.30000001192092895508 > (double) 0.29999999999999998890)`. Is this correct?

Comment: Please append "f" to the float values and post the results. If known it from Java, that the floating numbers not explicitly defined with "f" as an float will get an double. Probably some strange things happen when casting between float and double. It could be that 0.3 becomes to 0.30000000000000001 due to some rounding error.

Comment: Better yet, change all your variables to `double`.  All the math functions in C return `double`, so you might as well be consistent.  `float` is only useful for saving memory when you have an array of millions of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using `float` for storage, but you comparisons are being performed against the literals which are of type `double`.

The values of `x` and `y` aren't exactly 0.3 and 0.7, as those numbers aren't representable in binary floating point. It happens that the closest `float` to 0.3 is greater than the closest `double` to 0.3, and the closest `float` to 0.7 is less than the closest `double` to 0.7... hence your comparison results.

Assuming the representations are the same as in C# (where I happen to have some tools to help) the values involved are:

```
0.3 as float = 0.300000011920928955078125
0.3 as double = 0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875
0.7 as float = 0.699999988079071044921875
0.7 as double = 0.6999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875
```

So that explains why it's happening... but it doesn't explain how to work around the issue for whatever your code is actually trying to do, of course. If you can give more context to the bigger problem, we may be able to help more.

Comment: Actually, this question came up on a test paper I was practicing.

Answer (score 3):

Computers can't store floating point numbers exactly. Just like 1/7 can't be represented in a finite number of decimal digits, lots of numbers can't be represented exactly in binary. 3/10 is such a number. When you write `0.3` your program actually stores `0.30000001192092895508` as that's the best it can do with the 32 bits available to it in a `float` variable.

And it so happens that this value *also* differs from the `double` value of `0.3` since the computer can store more digits in a 64-bit `double`. When you write `if (x == 0.3)` your value is actually promoted to a `double` since floating-point constants are `double`s unless explicitly specified otherwise. It's equivalent to writing `if ((double) x == 0.3)`.

```
jkugelman$ cat float.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("%.20f\n", (float)  0.3);  // Can also be written "0.3f".
    printf("%.20f\n", (double) 0.3);  // Cast is redundant, actually.
    return 0;
}

jkugelman$ gcc -Wall -o float float.c

jkugelman$ ./float
0.30000001192092895508
0.29999999999999998890
```

Notice how the `0.2999...` value has more 9's in it than the `0.3000...` one. The double-precision value is closer to `0.3` thanks to the extra bits.

Comment: This is itself wouldn't cause `==` to fail if it was the *same* inexact value on both sides.  But the closest `float` to 0.3 is not the same as the closest `double` to 0.3.

Comment: So, my value is actually stored as a 32bit float. But when I use it somewhere, like in if-else statement, it's implicitly promoted to a double and all operations are performed on the double value. Is this correct?

Comment: @naruto: That's certainly the case when you compare it with a 64-bit float. I'm not sure whether there'd be any promotion involved internally if you were comparing it with another `float`, but as both values would be promoted in that case, I doubt it would make any difference.